# "Tô blow off with someone"

Tags: word-usage

If someone **blows off** something they should attend, they fail to show up for it. 
If they **blow someone off**, they ignore them.

Let's say someone is supposed to show up for a date with me, and the person never does. Instead of **She stood me me up** can I say "She **blew** (it) **off** with me"?

Answer (score 2):

That’s not idiomatic- particularly the “with me” part. Either “She blew off our date” or “She blew it off” (as long as it’s clear what “it” is from the context) would be ok. If you added “with me” it would sound like maybe both of you blew something off- but it would also sound confusing and unclear.